# why polymer prefers bower instead of webpack

Tags: webpack, bower, polymer-2.x

The tutorials at polymer web site are all referring to using bower instead of webpack, why is google still preferring bower?

https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to quote arthur on slack:
this had been answered here and elsewhere many times. Bower works now. None of the alternatives works now without extra tooling. And that extra tooling wasn't critical for 2.0, which was all about web components v1 support and a smooth upgrade path from 1.x.

So the team will be looking at this, but we need to support our existing 1.x and 2.x users and maintain 80+ elements at the same time.